# Is calling updateValueAndValidity is necessary after setting validators dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12

I was using `setAsyncValidators` though I went to doc in file `node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts`

and I sow following:

```
get updateOn(): FormHooks;
    /**
     * Sets the synchronous validators that are active on this control.  Calling
     * this overwrites any existing sync validators.
     *
     * When you add or remove a validator at run time, you must call
     * `updateValueAndValidity()` for the new validation to take effect.
     *
     */
    setValidators(newValidator: ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | null): void;
    /**
     * Sets the async validators that are active on this control. Calling this
     * overwrites any existing async validators.
     *
     * When you add or remove a validator at run time, you must call
     * `updateValueAndValidity()` for the new validation to take effect.
     *
     */
    setAsyncValidators(newValidator: AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[] | null): void;
    /**
     * Empties out the sync validator list.
     *
     * When you add or remove a validator at run time, you must call
     * `updateValueAndValidity()` for the new validation to take effect.
     *
     */
    clearValidators(): void;
    /**
     * Empties out the async validator list.
     *
     * When you add or remove a validator at run time, you must call
     * `updateValueAndValidity()` for the new validation to take effect.
     *
     */
    clearAsyncValidators(): void;
```

> Because everything worked perfectly without calling updateValueAndValidity so I'm confused is it necessary actually?

Comment: valid question, the doc claims we should @ https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl but it works without it (:confused:)

Comment: Okay, I now understand this.

If you dynamically add a validation it will not immediately validate the field. It will only validate the next time you update the form.

Whilst `updateValueAndValidity` will run/check the validation imediately.